# How to draw HPSG illustrations?

Tags: grammar, construction-grammar

everyone!I want to draw HPSG pictures like this,what tools can I use? Are there any HPSG illustration generators like http://mshang.ca/syntree/ ?(that link is a syntax tree generator)
[image]

Comment: This looks like standard LaTeX matrices to me. Is LaTeX an option for your purposes?

Comment: oh, I didn't thought about that!  Thanks! I'm not quite familiar with LaTex, so would you please tell me which package should I import if I use LaTex?

Comment: Use `avm` ("attribute-value matrices"): https://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/tex/

Comment: There is a mini-tutorial on avm.sty for LaTeX on Doug Arnold's website: https://www1.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/avms/